# Image URL issue in Larval 7

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-7

I am trying to hide the Image URL Larval 7 Application.

My image actual path is

```
storage/app/public/images/product_images
```

I have created a storage link using bellow command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

this creates a symbolic link in public directory `"storage"` to `"storage/app/public/"`

After that, I have created a new disk in `config/filesystems.php`

```
'images' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/images'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/images',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

in my view I have written this code to access the image

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="{{Storage::disk('images')->url('/product_images/'.$products_image)}}">
```

`$products_image` is getting the correct image name but the image is not showing.

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to achieve?
and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is the URL that ends up being generated for this call to `url` on the storage disk?

Comment: URL is being generated is: domain/images/product_images/image1.jpg , while image1.jpg exist

Comment: is it readable by the webserverf?

Comment: Yes, but if I put this code it shows the image {{asset('storage/images/product_images/'.$products_image)}}

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `storage` part of the URI for the `url` for that disk in the configuration.

Comment: can you please explain, I am new to Laravel

Comment: the path you are setting for `url` in that disks configuration is missing the `storage` part of it ... it is not the correct path that you are using from the root of the site .... just look at the difference between what it currently outputs for the URL and what your `asset` example from your comment outputs ... the one from using the disk is missing the `storage` part of the URL

Answer (score 0):

fix your url `env('APP_URL') . '/storage/images'` as it is stored in `storage_path()` so you need to append `storage`
`

```php
'images' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/images'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL') . 'storage/images',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: Hello, but this is again showing the same URL of the image, I want to remove 'storage' from url and show image also
domain/storage/images/product_images/image.jpg

Comment: where use public_path in blade?

Comment: no for upload image `'root' => public_path('images'),`  then you can use  `'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/images',`

Comment: Thanks, NO IMAGE
now my disk is like bellow
'root' => public_path('images'),
 'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/images/product_images',

and IN blade
{{Storage::disk('images')->url($products_image)}}

and URL in beowser is
http://domain/images/product_images/image.jpg

Comment: you need to upload image in new configure